# Android RadioButton only selected after first touch

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am writing a quiz program. It has an activity with two fragment. The first is a recycler view of the questions along the side. The second fragment contains a webview and 4 radiobuttons that exist in a radiobutton group. Looks like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P1wy.png)

When a radiobutton is pressed one of the actions taken is to use a callback to alert the recycler view to select a checkbox on the question item in the list to show that it has been answered.

But I've found that making the callback makes the radiobutton group not update the selected radiobutton **on the first press only**. On all subsequent touches radiobuttons update appropriately. I have stripped down my code to the barebones to find this problem and it seems to be the callback, but i really don't understand the issue. I have tried clearCheck() on the button group and setting the checked radiobutton manually. Neither has solved the problem.

I'm including code. OnCreateView in question fragment containers a listener. The listener calls updateDatabaseWithAnswer. updateDatabaseWithAnswer calls a callback to the main Activity that then tells the recyclerview in the other fragment to update. With the code as is, the recyclerView does update correctly and no errors are thrown.

The only way to fix this problem is by commenting out the second line of the callback (see comment in callback function). When that line is commented out the radiobuttons work correctly.

```
//QuestionFragement - contains radiobuttons and radiogroup
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    //answerButtonGroup
    mAnswerButtonGroup =(RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.answerButtonGroup);
    mAnswerButtonGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            updateDatabaseWithAnswered();
        }
    });
    return v;
    }

private void updateDatabaseWithAnswered(){
    int id = mQuestion.getId();
    int answerCorrect = 0; //0 = false, 1 = true
    if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getCorrectAnswer())){
        answerCorrect = 1;
    }
    mQuestion.setTimesUsed(mQuestion.getTimesUsed() + 1);
    mQuestion.setTimesCorrect(mQuestion.getTimesCorrect() + answerCorrect);
    updateQuestion();
}

private void updateQuestion(){
    ExamLab.get(getActivity()).updateDatabaseQuestionAnswered(mQuestion);
    //COMMENTING OUT THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE FIXES THE RADIOBUTTON PROBLEM
    mCallbacks.onQuestionUpdated(mQuestion, 0);
}

//ExamListActivity
/*
// Interface for QuestionFragment.Callback
 */
public void onQuestionUpdated(Question question,int changeSelectedQuestion){
    ExamListFragment listFragment = (ExamListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    listFragment.updateUI(changeSelectedQuestion);
}

//ExamListFragment - contains recyclerView
public void updateUI(int changeSelectedQuestion){
    ExamLab examLab = ExamLab.get(getActivity());
    List<Question> questions = examLab.getQuestions();

    if (mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new QuestionAdapter(questions);
        mExamRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        /*mAdapter.changeSelectedItem(changeSelectedQuestion);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
    }
    else {
        mAdapter.changeSelectedItem(changeSelectedQuestion);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the recyclerView is updated onCreateView the OS must be calling onCreateView for the QuestionFragment again. This problem was fixed by manually setting the checked question *outside* the radioButtonGroupListener rather than *inside* it. I still can't say that I understand exactly what is going on here, but it works now.

```
//QuestionFragement - contains radiobuttons and radiogroup
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
//answerButtonGroup
mAnswerButtonGroup =(RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.answerButtonGroup);

/*NEW CODE HERE*/
if (mQuestion.isUserAnsweredQuestion()) {
        setRadioButtonAnsweredDisplay();
        setChecked();
    }

mAnswerButtonGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        updateDatabaseWithAnswered();
    }
});
return v;
}

private void setChecked(){
    if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mRadioButtonChoice1.getText())){
        mRadioButtonChoice1.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mRadioButtonChoice2.getText())){
        mRadioButtonChoice2.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mRadioButtonChoice3.getText())){
        mRadioButtonChoice3.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mRadioButtonChoice4.getText())){
        mRadioButtonChoice4.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just an onclick function for the radiobuttons. Something similar to this:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            if (checked)
                //Your code
                break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if (checked)
                //Your code
                break;
    }
}
```

Then just set onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" for each radio button

Comment: Good idea. But "onClick" sends a message to the activity, not the fragment (I just experimented with it in my code). And I don't see any reason why the Activity should need to know about the fragment's UI specifics. Routing the message from the activity back down to the fragment seems a round-about and self-defeating way to go. Unless I'm told that's just the way it has to be. Is there a specific rationale you were thinking in terms of why OnCheckedChangedListener was the wrong way to go and onRadioButtonClicked is better?

Comment: So...I did do this completely. Took out radiogrouplistener. Added individual listeners for each radiobutton all going to the same function. When the callback is included in that function the exact same problem appears

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I misunderstood the question. Yeah you set up an onClickListener and then set up an interface to communicate between the fragment and the activity. I'll look at it again and then see if I can suggest something that might actually help.

Comment: Appreciate your help/ideas. This one is really baffling me.